# How to reset the camera's z and x rotation when entering a portal in VR?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I just started unity a few weeks ago, and I have no coding experience. I've been grinding to learn 12 hours a day but I can't write/modify my first script.

I got the base of my game off Github, and I managed to integrate VR into it by installing the necessary prerequisites. Now the game has a script called "RigidbodyCharacterController" which contains movement info and camera rotation for when you enter a horizontally placed portal. The issue is that it doesn't work in VR, contains useless movement info, and it's buggy, so i got rid of it. Now I just need a script that can reset the camera's z and x rotation axis each time I enter a portal.

[here's the old script:](https://gist.github.com/Lego-Dimensions/2898bf1d27f86e2d3ad770f799629777)

[here's the BasicPortal gameobject + components:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ES0mb.png)

[here's the rest of BasicPortal components:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHuD1.png)

Comment: Rather than including your script as a big image, make sure to show the relevant code (not necessarily all of it) as properly formatted text.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Lego-Dimensions/2898bf1d27f86e2d3ad770f799629777

Comment: @Bart Can you help or is it just a heads-up

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're going for here. At some point I'm going to assume you'll enter a portal, and then that's when you want to reset the camera rotations.

```
void OnEnterPortal()
{
    var cam = Camera.main;
    var rotation = cam.transform.eulerAngles;
    rotation.x = 0;
    rotation.z = 0;
    cam.transform.eulerAngles = rotation;
}
```

Then whenever you trigger the portal logic you call OnEnterPortal.

Comment: error CS1061: 'Transform' does not contain a definition for 'EulerAngles' and no accessible extension method 'EulerAngles' accepting a first argument of type 'Transform' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: can you provide the whole script ? @Chuck

Comment: @YourRainBoy sorry typo there I fixed it.

Comment: so i pasted that into an empty script, and it works! (no errors) but it doesn't rotate, did i miss something? or where do i place the script? into the cam, or the xr rig

Comment: https://youtu.be/WTskOXhE4zc

Comment: @YourRainBoy - where is the logic for the portal? Put the code there. If you're looking for how to realign the VR/XR headset then [here is a Unity forum thread on that](https://forum.unity.com/threads/proper-way-to-rotate-vr-camera.526337/). I gotta say though, going from no coding experience to making a VR/AR game is quite a leap. I'd highly encourage slowing down and trying out some tutorials.

Comment: I was just thinking of this while doing dishes lol, and I think we might be trying to help you fix a bandaid instead of treating the wound. WHY are you wanting to reset the x/z rotations? The point of AR/VR is to move the camera with the player's head, so I actually don't understand why you're wanting to reset the camera look angles or what you're trying to achieve there. The only actual angle I would think you might care about - yaw/y - you're not trying to mess with. Some more detail about what you're trying to accomplish instead of what you're doing now would probably get you more help.

Comment: I don't think you can rotate a camera with your own script. Because steamVR has full control of it. I think you could rotate the everything but player.

Comment: https://youtu.be/WTskOXhE4zc this is what i mean by rotation
i need to have the camera rotate back to how it was by the time you get out of the vertical portal in the video shown
if someone helps, i'll be eternally grateful @YGreater

Comment: hmm. you could put player in an empty gameObject and rotate that using code above. otherwise idk